# how to rename django image as id.jpg

Tags: python, django

My model in django is like this

```
meal_img_url=models.CharField(max_length=300,default=NULL)
meal_image=models.FileField(upload_to='mealsOne/static/meal_photos');
package_cost = models.FloatField(default=0)

def __unicode__(self):
    os.system("mv "+str(self.meal_image.name)+" mealsOne/static/meal_photos/web/"+str(self.id)+".jpg")
    self.meal_image.name='static/meal_photos/web/'+str(self.id)+".jpg"
    self.meal_img_url='http://instomeal.com/'+self.meal_image.name
    self.save()
```

But it is taking too much time for move operation every time. So is there any alternative way to save file with id (ex : id.jpg) ?

Comment: It would be faster to use `os.rename()` or `shutil.move()` than calling system command `mv` I think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You pass a function to `upload_to`. There you can set the filename and path of the image (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.FileField.upload_to).
The function could look like this

```
def get_image_name(instance, filename):
    fn = 'mealsOne/static/meal_photos/%s.jpg' % instance.id
    return fn
```

And in you model pass this function

```
meal_image=models.FileField(upload_to=get_image_name);
```

### UPDATE:

If the object is not yet created, there is no `id` set. Then you can overwrite the `save` method of the model and do there the renaming.

```
def save(self):
    super(Model, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
    # now the id is set
    # rename your image with os.rename
    ....
```

You can also do this using djangos `post_save` signal (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/signals/#post-save)

Comment: I already tried this. But instance.id returning None Type. I mean without creating the object instance cannot have id.

Comment: I see. Do you really need the id or just a unique filename? If you want to use the id you probably have to rename the image. But you should do this in the `save` method. Definitely not in the `__unicode__` method!

Comment: Please give me the some reference about save method.

Comment: If the answer helped you, would be great if you could accept and upvote it :)

Answer (score -1):

A few notes:

- don't use '+' to join urls, use [urlparse.urljoin](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html#urlparse.urljoin)
- for filesystem paths use [os.path.join](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.join)
- why would use use "mv" and "self.save" in the **unicode** function which should be used for "rendering" the object?